# How to write apache module in C through which to retrieve POST form data from browser?

Tags: c, apache

I have already written an `Apache` module in `c` and parsed GET data from browser through:

```
r->args
```

But I don't know how I retrieve the POST form data. Can anybody suggest to me how?